# Problemas com $_SESSION

Tags: php

Tenho um problema pra resolver. Tenho o mesmo site em vários servidores diferentes, porém um apresenta diferente resultado. Parece que tem algum erro, não sei se é configuração.

Eis o seguinte código de teste que fiz:

```
session_start();  
if(!isset($_SESSION["funcio"]) || !isset($_SESSION["senha"])){  
require_once "sair.php";  
}  
print $_SESSION["funcio"];  
$_POST['funcio'] = '1';    
$funcio = '2';  
print $funcio;  
print $_POST['funcio'];  
print $_SESSION["funcio"];
```

Resultados:
Nos sites que funcionam normalmente o resultdo é

> Admsite 2 1 Admsite

No site que apresenta problema, o resultado é

> Adm 2 1 2

Conclusão:
Ao declarar a variável $funcio com o mesmo nome da `$_SESSION["funcio"]` e definir seu valor,a variável `$_SESSION["funcio"]` assume o valor de da variável `$funcio`.
Isso está me dando um grande transtorno. Peço ajuda pra resolver essa questão. Já olhei no `php.ini` e nos dois servidores está praticamente o mesmo. 
Abraços

---

já verifiquei, os valores de $_SESSION["funcio"] estão corretos, mas nesse servidor, quando crio uma variável $funcio e defino seu valor, a variável $_SESSION["funcio"] assume o valor da variável criada.

Percebi que isso ocorre não apenas com essa variável, mas com todas as variávei do tipo $_SESSION cujo nome é o mesmo de variáveis que crio.

O que será isso?

Comment: Não está entrando dentro da condição if ? pois se entrar pode ser que na sair.php algo de um echo 2 e imprima nessa dai

Comment: Não está entrando na condição if, se tivesse, sairia do programa. Pois o sair.php sai da página e elimina todas as variáveis. Ali no caso, ele ainda imprime os valores das variáveis.

Comment: E como está a configuração `register_globals`? Parece que ela está ativa. Se sim, evite usá-la, pois está obsoleta.

Comment: register_globals = Off

Comment: já verifiquei, os valores de $_SESSION["funcio"] estão corretos, mas nesse servidor, quando crio uma variável $funcio e defino seu valor, a variável $_SESSION["funcio"] assume o valor da variável criada.

Percebi que isso ocorre não apenas com essa variável, mas com todas as variávei do tipo $_SESSION cujo nome é o mesmo de variáveis que crio.

O que será isso?

Comment: A configuração `register_globals = Off` é neste servidor? Qual a versão do PHP?

Comment: No que está dando erro  a versão é PHP Version 5.3.26, no que está dando corretamente a versão é PHP Version 5.2.17. O register_globals = Off está no php.ini, mas vou verificar nas configurações do php.

Comment: Após dar o comando phpinfo(), verifiquei que register_globals está on, mas no php.ini está off. Como resolver essa questão?